# Integrating Pubnub push notifications

Tags: certificate, pubnub

I'm trying to integrate Pubnub in my react-native app.

I followed this guide for the platform integration : 
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway

when I try to upload Apple certificate into Pubnub dashboard I get this error :
`error decoding pem password was given but private key is not encrypted`

I don't fully understand what it means and how to solve this.

Comment: Try generating a new cert without a pasword and convert to pem. That should fix it. Let me know.

Comment: Did my advice resolve you issue or do you still have the issue?

Comment: I managed to do so, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**: Used a password when generating an APNS push certificate.

**Solution**: regenerate the push certificate without a password and convert to `.pem` again and it should work.

Also, if you get an error uploading your `.pem` file, it might be corrupted and cause a similar error. Same solution - try regenerating the push cert and convert to `.pem`.